# Microsoft Graph get direct reports additional properties

Tags: rest, microsoft-graph-api

When accessing MS Graph and fetching my direct reports I get basic information back about the user such as `givenName`, `jobTitle`, etc. The problem is I also want some other properties such as skills and `pastProjects`, however I don't seem to be able to access these details.

I've included some Urls I've tried but none of them seem to return any soft skill type properties

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/directReports

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/directReports?$select=givenName,skills

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/directReports?$select=givenName,jobTitle,skills,pastProjects,mail,schools,interests,responsibilities,mobilePhone
```

In all cases the basic user details are returned but I'm not able to get `skills` or `pastProjects`.

I can make a direct call to the user to fetch these, see url below, but ideally I want to avoid another call if possible.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/?$select=givenName,jobTitle,skills,pastProjects
```

Answer (score 0):

Some properties may only be retrieved with an individual user. This is noted in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0):

> Note: Certain properties cannot be returned within a user collection. The following properties are only supported when retrieving an single user: *aboutMe, birthday, hireDate, interests, mySite, pastProjects, preferredName, responsibilities, schools, skills, mailboxSettings*